# How to filter packets marked by 'so_mark' using TC

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, trafficshaping

I use `so_mark` to mark packets sent from a specific socket.
Now I want to filter these packets from a class in my TC (from HTB mechanism actually).
What is the filter to be used (and syntax example will be helpful as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone wondered :

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match mark 0x123 0xFFF flowid 1:1
```